# How to make new DRF 3.6 built-in documentation work?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried to setup the new Django Rest Framework built-in documentation, following the (unusually succint) [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/#built-in-api-documentation).

For now, I get a page with a 401 unauthorized error, and I can't see my endpoints. When clicking on session authentication, I get the message bellow.

[image]

However, I'm already session-logged as a superuser in another tab.

Here is the code I have so far:

**urls.py**

```
root_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),  # Api endpoints
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),  # Admin
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API')),  # Built-in DRF documentation
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^backend/', include(root_urlpatterns))
]
```

**api/urls.py**

```
endpoints_urlpatterns = [

    url(regex=r'^customers/activate/$',
        view=views_customer.ActivateCustomerView.as_view(),
        name="activate-customer"),

]

VERSION = 1

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^{}/'.format(VERSION), include(endpoints_urlpatterns))
]
```

All required packages (coreapi, Pygments, markdown) are pip-installed.
Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you add your Permission Classes and Authentication classes as well?

Comment: You're right that was the problem: `SessionAuthentication`was missing from the list of `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` setting. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that SessionAuthentication is there too:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
```